# How to add "Other Category" for sentences that do not match predefined 4 categories?

Tags: weka, text-classification

I am using SMO algorithm in weka to classify sentences in 4 categories. My question is how i can add other or unclassified category for sentences that do not match the 4 predefined categories. What is the best approach to handle this problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to build a classifier on top by joining all 4 categories.

http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/oneClassClassifier/

This has to be installed separately from tools>package manager.
Add the jar from 
C:\Users\username\wekafiles\packages\oneClassClassifier\oneClassClassifier.jar